# Particle Effects java slick

Tags: java, slick2d

I have made a java class extending BasicGameState of java slick2d library.To test particle effects  I used the ParticleSystem. But the xml file doesn't load. It gives unable to load the emitter error. This is the code of emitter loading.

```
private ParticleSystem system ;

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
    Image image = new Image("res/particle.png",false);
    system = new ParticleSystem(image,1500);

    try{
        File xmlFile = new File("res/particle.xml");
        ConfigurableEmitter emitter = ParticleIO.loadEmitter("res/particle.xml");
        emitter.setPosition(315,358);
        system.addEmitter(emitter);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception: "+ e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    system.setBlendingMode(ParticleSystem.BLEND_ADDITIVE);
}
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: What does your folder structure look like?

Comment: Add " System.out.println(new File("res/particle.xml").getAbsolutePath());" right before you call "ParticleIO.loadEmitter", is the xml file located in that location?